# Filter array from duplicated arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[5,3],[6,2],[7,1]];
```

All I want is to filter them from duplicate arrays. So it will look like:

```
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4]];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Guys, these links you posted doesnt have any solution for my problem.

Comment: Plain javascript? No jQuery or underscore?

Comment: @kindguy123, does the order of items matter? just want to know, should I adjust my answer. It gives `[
  [
    "4",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "3",
    "5"
  ],
  [
    "2",
    "6"
  ],
  [
    "1",
    "7"
  ]
]`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `filter()`, `some()` and `every()`.

```js
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[5,3],[6,2],[7,1]];

var result = arr.filter(function(e) {
  var r = this.some(function(a) {
    return e.every(function(b) {
      return a.includes(b)
    })
  })
  if (!r) {
    this.push(e);
    return e
  }
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

If you want to use arrow functions you can also write it like this.

```js
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[5,3],[6,2],[7,1]];

var result = arr.filter(function(e) {
  return !this.some(a =>e.every(b =>a.includes(b))) ? this.push(e) && e : false
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hash table and use the joined string of the sorted array as hash.

```js
var arr = [[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1]],
    result = arr.filter(function(a) {
        var hash = a.slice().sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }).join();
        if (!this[hash]) {
            this[hash] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with Set

```js
var asc = (a, b) => a - b,
    join = a => a.slice().sort(asc).join(),
    arr = [[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1]],
    result = arr.filter((hash => a => (h => !hash.has(h) && hash.add(h))(join(a)))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution:

First of all, you should sort `arrays` to look like : `[[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[3,5],[2,6],[1,7]]`, and then eliminate `duplicates`.

Use `filter` function for filtering the values from array. `seen` its a dictionary and i'm using it for verify if the current value was found in it(seen dictionary).If yes, "remove" value from array. If not,set that the current array was used and go to the next item. I said "remove" because `filter` function **creates a new array**.

`filter` function is easy to understand. Learn more about it, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[5,3],[6,2],[7,1]];
arr.forEach(function(array){
    array.sort((a,b)=>a>b);
});
var seen = {};
var uniqueArray = arr.filter(function(item) {
      return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
 });
console.log(uniqueArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using 
`Array.prototype.map()` ,
 `Array.prototype.filter()`, 
`Array.prototype.join()`, `String.prototype.split()` functions:

```js
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[5,3],[6,2],[7,1]];

result = arr.map(function (a) {
    a.sort();
    return a.join();
}).filter(function (inner_arr, idx, a) {
    return idx === a.lastIndexOf(inner_arr);
}).map(function(s){
    return s.split(',');
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not the same order the OP asked for... can't say if that matters or not though

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, all solutions keep original array intact. 
If that's not problem, here is one more meat&potatoes™, straightforward solution:

```js
var arr = [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4,4],[5,3],[6,2],[7,1]];


temp=[];
unique=[];
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
str=arr[i].sort().toString();
if(temp.indexOf(str)===-1) {
temp.push(str);
unique.push(arr[i]);
}
}



console.log(unique);
```